# program a wall in which an object can not pass

Tags: programming, grid-layouts, mathematica-online

This is the code we have created so far for a Pacman type game:

```
`DynamicModule[{diskPosition = {250, 450}, diskRadius = 15, 
  pacman = {9, 4}}, 
 EventHandler[
  Graphics[Dynamic[{Yellow, Disk[diskPosition, diskRadius, pacman]}],

   PlotRange -> {{0, 460}, {0, 590}}, Background -> Black],

  {
   "LeftArrowKeyDown" :> {(pacman = {9, 4}), (diskPosition[[
        1]] += -10)},

   "RightArrowKeyDown" :> {(pacman = {1, 6}), (diskPosition[[1]] += 
       10)},

   "UpArrowKeyDown" :> {(pacman = {2, 7}), (diskPosition[[2]] += 10)},

   "DownArrowKeyDown" :> {(pacman = {-2, -7}), (diskPosition[[
        2]] += -10)}

   }]]`
```

We want to create a grid which the pacman cannot pass through the barriers, creating a maze it must go through.

Comment: It might be easier to build a path along which the pacman can move (rather than a wall that it cannot cross).

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: How would would I build a path that the pacman can only move on?

Answer (score 8):

Before making a move, test if the new position is a valid position. A valid position is one where Pac-Man does not touch the walls. *Mathematica* has convenient functions that deal with regions, so we might consider creating a region and then using those functions. Regions can be built using `Graphics` primitives and then converted into regions with `DiscretizeGraphics`, therefore we will first create a graphics object of the map. I decided to start from this image:

[image]

I used some image processing functions to turn the map into a region, but note that you can create your map by hand using `Rectangle`, `Line`, `Polygon` or whatever you may want.

```
img = ImageCrop@Binarize@Import["http://wallpapercave.com/wp/6SKGas2.png"];
components = MorphologicalComponents[Thinning[img]];
indices = DeleteCases[DeleteDuplicates@Flatten[components], 0];
curvePathPlots = ListCurvePathPlot[Position[components, #]] & /@ indices;
lines = Cases[Show[curvePathPlots, PlotRange -> All], _Line, Infinity];
```

`lines` now contains `Line` objects corresponding to all the lines. We now create the map, for displaying as a background, and the region, for collision checking.

```
map = Graphics[{Thickness[0.004], White, lines}, Background -> Black];
region = DiscretizeGraphics[map];
```

Evaluate `map` to see what it looks like, put a white disk of radius 20 in as well for scale:

```
Show[
 map,
 Graphics[{White, Disk[{420, 425}, 20]}]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Because of a change of coordinate system we've rotated the image, but it doesn't matter. The one who cares about it, may fix it.

Now we need a function that will tell us if a Pac-Man, represented as a disk of radius 20, collides with the walls, if it is positioned at a certain position. Since it is a disk it is equivalent to checking whether the distance to the wall is larger than 20:

```
freeQ[{x_, y_}] := RegionDistance[region, {x, y}] > 20
```

Now, an event in the `EventHandler` may look like this:

```
"LeftArrowKeyDown" :> If[freeQ[diskPosition - {10, 0}],
  pacman = {9, 4};
  diskPosition[[1]] += -10
  ]
```

This says "if the new position will not cause Pac-Man to collide with any wall, make the move." Here is your updated code:

```
DynamicModule[
 {
  diskPosition = {510, 470},
  diskRadius = 20,
  pacman = {9, 4}
  },
 EventHandler[Show[
   map,
   Graphics[
    Dynamic[{Yellow, Disk[diskPosition, diskRadius, pacman]}],
    PlotRange -> {{0, 460}, {0, 590}}
    ]
   ],
  {
   "LeftArrowKeyDown" :> If[freeQ[diskPosition - {10, 0}],
     pacman = {9, 4};
     diskPosition[[1]] += -10
     ],
   "RightArrowKeyDown" :> If[freeQ[diskPosition + {10, 0}],
     pacman = {1, 6};
     diskPosition[[1]] += 10;
     ],
   "UpArrowKeyDown" :> If[freeQ[diskPosition + {0, 10}],
     pacman = {2, 7};
     diskPosition[[2]] += 10
     ],
   "DownArrowKeyDown" :> If[freeQ[diskPosition - {0, 10}],
     pacman = {-2, -7};
     diskPosition[[2]] += -10
     ]
   }]]
```

[image: Pac-Man test run]

Comment: This code is great except our pacman will only move along the center box. Any idea why our pacman can't move around the entire map?

Comment: @pacman I think I demonstrate in my animation that the Pac-Man can in fact move around the entire map?

Comment: I tried it out but for some reason it only goes around the center box.

Comment: @pacman I just tried it too. There was a slight change of image size when I uploaded the image, so I had to adjust the starting position (I've now incorporated this into answer), but other than that it runs fine... I'm using version 11, but I expect it to work in Mathematica 10 as well.

Answer (score 7):

Here's a maze for the pacman to operate in (which is taken from [here](https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/new-in-10/enhanced-graphs-and-networks/maze-generator.html))

```
style = {Background -> GrayLevel[0], 
   BaseStyle -> {Directive[White, EdgeForm[], Opacity[1]]}, 
   VertexShapeFunction -> (Rectangle[#1 + .16, #1 - .16] &), 
   EdgeShapeFunction -> (Rectangle[#1[[1]] + .16, #1[[2]] - .16] &)};
embedding = GraphEmbedding[GridGraph[{20, 30}]]; 
g = GridGraph[{20, 30}, EdgeWeight -> RandomReal[10, 1150]];
tree = FindSpanningTree[{g, 1}]; 
maze = Binarize[Image[Rasterize[Graph[tree, VertexCoordinates->embedding, style], 
       RasterSize -> 1000], ImageSize -> 1000]];
m = 5;
```

Now the pac man in-the-maze, constrained with the If[] statements to the white portions of the maze.

```
DynamicModule[{diskPosition = {250, 450}, diskRadius = 15, pacman = {9, 4}}, 
 EventHandler[
  Show[maze, Graphics[Dynamic[{Yellow, Disk[diskPosition, diskRadius, pacman]}],
     PlotRange -> {{0, 200}, {0, 300}}]], 
{"RightArrowKeyDown" :> 
    If[PixelValue[maze, {diskPosition[[1]] + m, diskPosition[[2]]}] == 1, 
                  pacman = {1, 6}; diskPosition[[1]] += m],
 "LeftArrowKeyDown" :> 
    If[PixelValue[maze, {diskPosition[[1]] - m, diskPosition[[2]]}] == 1, 
                  pacman = {9, 4}; diskPosition[[1]] += -m],
 "UpArrowKeyDown" :> 
    If[PixelValue[maze, {diskPosition[[1]], diskPosition[[2]] + m}] == 1, 
                  pacman = {2, 7}; diskPosition[[2]] += m],
 "DownArrowKeyDown" :> 
    If[PixelValue[maze, {diskPosition[[1]], diskPosition[[2]] - m}] == 1, 
                  pacman = {-2, -7}; diskPosition[[2]] += -m]}]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

here is an idea..crude but may show how to proceed.

```
box = {{50, 200}, {300, 200}, {300, 400}, {50, 400}, {50, 200}};
up[p_] := 
 Module[ {t = p + {0, 10}}, 
  If[ 200 - 15 < t[[2]] < 400 + 15 && 50 < t[[1]] < 300 , 0, 10]]
left[p_] := 
 Module[ {t = p - {10, 0}}, 
  If[ 200 < t[[2]] < 400 && 50 - 15 < t[[1]] < 300 + 15, 0, -10]]
right[p_] := 
 Module[ {t = p + {10, 0}}, 
  If[ 200 < t[[2]] < 400 && 50 - 15 < t[[1]] < 300 + 15, 0, 10]]
down[p_] := 
 Module[ {t = p - {0, 10}}, 
  If[ 200 - 15 < t[[2]] < 400 + 15 && 50 < t[[1]] < 300 , 0, -10]]
DynamicModule[
 {diskPosition = {250, 450}, diskRadius = 15, pacman = {9, 4}}, 
 EventHandler[
  Graphics[{Dynamic[{Yellow, Disk[diskPosition, diskRadius, pacman]}],
     Thick, White, Line[box]}, PlotRange -> {{0, 460}, {0, 590}}, 
   Background -> Black], {
   "LeftArrowKeyDown" :> {(pacman = {9, 4}), (diskPosition[[1]] += 
       left[diskPosition])},
   "RightArrowKeyDown" :> {(pacman = {1, 6}), (diskPosition[[1]] += 
       right[diskPosition])},
   "UpArrowKeyDown" :> {(pacman = {2, 7}), (diskPosition[[2]] += 
       up[diskPosition])}, 
   "DownArrowKeyDown" :> {(pacman = {-2, -7}), (diskPosition[[2]] += 
       down[diskPosition])}}]]
```

as noted in comment it may be better to define a permissible path, which would amount to a list of permissible positions on a `10x10` grid. Then as you do each update you check if the updated position is in the permissible list ( `MemberQ` maybe. )

```
grid = Table[ {i, 450}, {i, 100, 400, 10}]~Join~
   Table[ {100, j}, {j, 100, 500, 10}];
up[p_] := Module[ {t = p + {0, 10}}, If[ MemberQ[grid, t] , 10, 0]]
left[p_] := Module[ {t = p - {10, 0}}, If[ MemberQ[grid, t] , -10, 0]]
right[p_] := Module[ {t = p + {10, 0}}, If[ MemberQ[grid, t] , 10, 0]]
down[p_] := Module[ {t = p - {0, 10}}, If[ MemberQ[grid, t] , -10, 0]]
DynamicModule[
 {diskPosition = {250, 450}, diskRadius = 15, pacman = {9, 4}}, 
 EventHandler[
  Graphics[{Dynamic[{Yellow, Disk[diskPosition, diskRadius, pacman]}],
     White, Point[grid]}, PlotRange -> {{0, 460}, {0, 590}}, 
   Background -> Black], {
   "LeftArrowKeyDown" :> {(pacman = {9, 4}), (diskPosition[[1]] += 
       left[diskPosition])},
   "RightArrowKeyDown" :> {(pacman = {1, 6}), (diskPosition[[1]] += 
       right[diskPosition])},
   "UpArrowKeyDown" :> {(pacman = {2, 7}), (diskPosition[[2]] += 
       up[diskPosition])}, 
   "DownArrowKeyDown" :> {(pacman = {-2, -7}), (diskPosition[[2]] += 
       down[diskPosition])}}]]
```

[image]